# Fantasy book possibly set in middle eastern area

Tags: story-identification

The girl had her back painted (or tattooed) and was dressing up for a wedding or some special event and for some reason it never went away it just got more vivid. I think it was gold and red. I think the tattoo had something to do with magic.

I think they were in the market at some point and somebody told her the story about how she made eyes at a man and they got married

The book was probably from the 2000s

I believe the book was set on the middle east/Arabian area

Comment: Do you remember anything about the story? In particular what makes this a *fantasy* story?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You might be able to improve your question by going through the [suggestions for a good story-id question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407)

Comment: Maybe you can find it on this list of books about tattoo magic: https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/108729.Books_Featuring_Tattoo_Magic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Kiss of Deception](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16429619.The_Kiss_of_Deception__The_Remnant_Chronicles___1_) by Mary E. Pearson

> In a society steeped in tradition, Princess Lia’s life follows a
>   preordained course. As First Daughter, she is expected to have the
>   revered gift of sight—but she doesn’t—and she knows her parents are
>   perpetrating a sham when they arrange her marriage to secure an
>   alliance with a neighboring kingdom—to a prince she has never met.
>
> On the morning of her wedding, Lia flees to a distant village. She
>   settles into a new life, hopeful when two mysterious and handsome
>   strangers arrive—and unaware that one is the jilted prince and the
>   other an assassin sent to kill her. Deception abounds, and Lia finds
>   herself on the brink of unlocking perilous secrets—even as she finds
>   herself falling in love.

[This review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1341708378?book_show_action=false) mentions Lia's going through the painstaking process of having a wedding kavah tattooed on her back (like a henna tattoo but a little more painful). And one [previous searcher](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/19731559-solved-fantasy-romance-a-royalty-and-back-tattoo-story-s) remembers the tattoo as supposed to be temporary but in Lia's case, as she doesn’t marry, it becoming more and more vivid.